# Splitting a sequence of assignments into self-named groups

Tags: regex

I have the following two sample entries in my logs:

1) `foo=bar,hello=world`

2) `a=b,c=d,x=y`

Along with these samples, there are many other different variable assignments, such that it is not feasible write regex to catch every possible assignment. However, all assignments are a list of comma delimited `variable=value` assignments according the samples above.

I'm looking to write some regex to split these entries into named groups, automatically.

For the first example, we would have the following named groups:

```
foo=bar
hello=world
```

For the second example, we would end up with the following named groups:

```
a=b
c=d
x=y
```

Can we do this with regex?

Comment: Regex patterns just match text, if you need to arrange the matches into some specific structure, you need some programming language features. What is the programming language?

Comment: value can hold what kind of values ? simplest thing is split by `,` if your values doesn't include any `,`

Answer (score 0):

Regex :

```
 ([^,]+)

Match 1
1.  foo=bar
Match 2
1.  hello=world

Match 1
1. a=b
Match 2
1.  c=d
Match 3
1.  x=y
```